# Intermittent Login Issues with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security

I have a strange one. I've been experiencing occasional login errors via windows authentication for the past couple weeks and the network team and I have yet to find a solution.

I am running SQL 2016 on a physical server running Windows Server 2012 R2.

While this has been happening, I've been telling users to wait five minutes and try to login again. If the user waits five minutes, they will (most times) be able to login. I've had instances where I couldn't log in for 15 minutes, then my next login attempt works.

From the SQL error log, I see entries like this:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication. [CLIENT: XX.XX.XXX.XXX]   Error: 18452,
>   Severity: 14, State: 1.
>
> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090311, state 14 while
>   establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has
>   been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error
>   code indicates the cause of failure. No authority could be contacted
>   for authentication.   [CLIENT: XX.XX.XXX.XXX] Error: 17806, Severity:
>   20, State: 14.

From the server, I see this:

> An account failed to log on.
>
> Subject:  Security ID:        NULL SID    Account Name:       -   Account Domain:     -
>     Logon ID:       0x0
>
> Logon Type:           3
>
> Account For Which Logon Failed:   Security ID:        NULL SID    Account
>   Name:     A User  Account Domain:     A Domain
>
> Failure Information:  Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
>     Status:         0xC000005E  Sub Status:     0x0
>
> Process Information:  Caller Process ID:  0x0     Caller Process Name:    -
>
> Network Information:  Workstation Name:   A Computer  Source Network
>   Address:  -   Source Port:        -
>
> Detailed Authentication Information:  Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
>     Authentication Package: NTLM    Transited Services: -   Package Name
>   (NTLM only):  -   Key Length:     0

Any ideas what could be causing (sometimes) login failures like this?

Comment: Taking a guess, it sounds like a replication issue with one or more Domain Controllers due to the fact the issue is intermittent.

Comment: Is it possible you are using a backup domain controller or that the domain controller is simply overwhelmed? Is this the only server using this DC, or is the problem also reproducible on other servers? It also could be some kind of packet loss issue - it doesn't seem like the DC is unreachable, more like the data it receives isn't always complete.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I welcome any/all guesses. This is the only server I know of having this issue. It is special, in that it is a secondary in a high availability group and is located off site, with the two sites connected via a 10 GB pipe. Now, that being said, for the first two and a half months offsite, there were none of these connection issues. The network guy I'm working with has been focusing on the domain controller. Maybe we're on the right path.

Comment: I am not really sure if this would help you or not, are you using fully qualified name for server name when trying to access the server. I meant if server name is ABC-DEF and domain name is company.com. We should be using ABC-DEF@company.com and same should be applicable for login. If login is TestLogin then login should be used as company.com\TestLogin. Otherwise for server name, you may use direct IP(if clustered then VIP)

Answer (score 7):

> SSPI handshake failed with error code **0x80090311**, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. No authority could be contacted for authentication.

If you cut up the HRESULT listed, as the error indicates, it maps to:
`SEC_E_NO_AUTHENTICATING_AUTHORITY`

FAILURE (1), FACILITY_SSPI (0x9), Code 0x311

> Failure Information: Failure Reason: An Error occured during Logon. Status: **0xC000005E** Sub Status: 0x0

If you cut up the HRESULT listed in this one, it maps to: `STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS`

Both of these error are fairly indicative that the domain controllers and infrastructure around them should be investigated. Additionally if it's a single server having the issue, look at recent patches or group policy items that have been pushed, recently, especially due to OU changes or membership changes. If others on the same network are having issues, network hardware or improper domain controller resources might be an issue.

Comment: Check the server error log on both the sql server and the DC. It will probably be revealing.